# how to unset a field in meteor simple schema

Tags: meteor, meteor-autoform, simple-schema

I want to unset a field in simpleSchema but the field is neither shown in set or unset under hooks

```
before:{
 update:function(mod){
   console.log(mod["$set"]);
   console.log(mod["$unset"])
```

This is what I have done to unset

```
'mobility.walkerType':{
  type:String,
  optional:true,
  label:"WalkerType",
  autoValue:function(){
    if(this.siblingField('type').value != "walker"){
      this.unset();
    }
  },
}
```

Comment: Trying returning `undefined` explicitly after `this.unset()`.  Another user ran into this recently and I have a suspicion that might do it?